# Drop and Head Giving AttributeError When Reading from Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import many sheets into the python and use pandas to do the data wrangling.

I tried to use the `drop()` function to delete the first row of the first sheet. Here is the code I'm using in my Jupyter notebook:

```
data = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', sheet_name = ['Table1'])
data
data.drop(data.index[0])
```

But this errors with:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Attribute Error                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-bec99022822c> in <module>()
      1 data = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', sheet_name = ['Table1'])
      2 data
----> 3 data.drop(data.index[0])

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'drop'
```

I also tried

```
data.head()
```

But it gave this error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Attribute Error                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-304fa4ce4ebd> in <module>()
----> 1 data.head()

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'head'
```

How can I use the `drop()` and `head()` functions?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: you passed a `list` to `read_excel`.

When you do that, even a `list` with one element, `pandas` will return an `OrderedDict` containing one `DataFrame` for each sheet.

Do `data = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', sheet_name='Table1')` and you'll be fine.

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you passed a list of sheets to open, and now Pandas has returned a dictionary of pandas-dataframe.

You can either pass a single sheet_name, or alternatively you can do following in your example

```
data = pd.read('something.xlsx', sheet_name =[*list_of_sheets*])
data['*sheet_name*'].drop(data.index[0], axis=0)
```

Hope this helps